# Howto handle infinispan cache creating and deployment

Tags: caching, jboss, infinispan

We have a infinispan cluster serving as cache server for our applications. Every time we need a new cache, we have to edit the config files, and redeploy the cluster, which is problematic. For obvious reasons, we don't want to redeploy the cache cluster.
We can add the new cache definition through web interface, or cli. But it has downside of not recording this configuration in a repo. Ideally I want to be able to add cache definitions in a way that is persistent in my code repo. So that in case of a disaster, I can simply redeploy the cache cluster.

We looked into creating cache definition through the source code, at application startup, but that doesn't seems to be possible.

Does anyone has an idea about the best practises for this issue?

Comment: Crosslink to JBoss forums: https://developer.jboss.org/message/970594

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some R&D, this is what we found:

- Programatic creation of the caches, are possible through jcache implementation in Infinispan, but we could not find a way to properly configure it. End result is just an empty cache definition, with no properties
- What we ended up doing is to create caches using jboss cli. Use an script to create the cache definitions, and commit that script to version control system. This way you can recreate your cache server anytime by rerunning that script. The downside of this approach is that you are going to need to install jboss-cli on your deploying machine - CI probably- which is very inconvenient. We just decided to do this step manually for time being.

Comment: We're working on easier ways to create caches remotely that will overcome the obstacles you've found. Stay tuned :)